# Ember - The last test in my file structure always gets added to the test module i'm viewing

Tags: testing, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a strange bug when running tests in Ember (w/CLI) where the last test that is in my directory is added to any of the individual test modules. The last test always breaks and if I delete the last file it will move on to the penultimate test and append that test. The tests fails with a Global Error message

Any ideas why it would append the last test to any of my individual tests?

Comment: What's the error?  Anything in the console?

Comment: do you need/require ember-cli or could you use gulp instead? to help nail down the issue if nothing else

Comment: The console error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of null". It's like it's trying to start a new qUnit module, but doesn't have a legitimate currentModule (=null). I noticed it because it appends the last test name to the browser.

Comment: @ToranBillups yes it has to be ember-cli (for work). Though I've heard good things about Gulp :)